# Weird red dotted rectangle appearing in blender, how do I delete it?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm not even able to select it, also don't think its an object. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tapped on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Try tapping <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to clear the region.

Preferences > Keymap > 3d View:
[image: Preferences > Keymap > 3d View]

For more info see [Borders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html#borders)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: You are welcome. I made that mistake as bloody beginner a few times...and was lost too. my advice: do not tap any keys just because you want to find the right one, because nearly every key combination "does" something in blender.  So only use key shortcuts from which you are sure what they do! ;)

Comment: That one in particular does something in object mode and something different in edit mode.  Something else to watch out for.

Comment: @Allen: you are totally right. You also have to check where, and in which modes you are. Even in another window it means something different e.g. in outliner or in 3d View. And i tried as beginner to find my keys....and got lost so many times... :( but nobody said: don't try out short-cuts :(